# The system is running in low graphics mode after changing root password

Tags: drivers, graphics, permissions

My ubuntu was working ( it was having a working graphics driver), *but I changed my root password then immediately the power was gone ( forced shutdown)*.

Then next time I restart my ubuntu I get this error:

> The system is running in low graphics mode

I have seen this [How to fix "The system is running in low-graphics mode" error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error) but it talks about installing and updating drivers and I dont think I need that.

*I am looking for explanation that relates root password change and the error message I get*

***update***:
when I hit `ctrl+alt+F1` on recovery mode boot it gets stuck after printing:
   `Loading extension GLX`

Thanks,

Comment: Apparently due to lack of disk space. See answer [How to fix "The system is running in low-graphics mode" error?](//askubuntu.com/a/138729) to the dupe target

Answer (score 0):

Run `grep EE /var/log/Xorg.0.log`

I'd you get something similar to: 
`[ 247.145] (EE) open /dev/dri/card): No such file or directory`

Then the problem lies in having a video driver set up wrong. For example if you have an intel video card and have a Nvidia driver installed it won't work.

Run `lspci` and find your video adapter. If it's mixed matched you can run a purge command :

`sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*`

Where nvidia is an example for a driver that needs intel, but is instead forced with an Nvidia driver

Comment: Thanks, but see below what the problem was.

Answer (score 0):

While it is stuck saying:
`Loading extension GLX`

I hit `ctrl+c` then it was logging a lot things ( most of them daemon activities) very fast , then lucky enough I saw a line that says *your system is having low disk space*.

Then:

1. I restarted to recovery mode again
2. Choose root [drop to root]
3. Then going to the directories I stored my files; I created some space(deleted some video files that I dont need)
4. Reboot
5. **my system is working**!